# Why are my .cs files automatically locked, and aspx.cs files not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, version-control, visual-studio-2015

If I edit a .cs file in Visual Studio that's under source control (TFS 2010), it gets automatically checked out and locked. I don't want it to be locked, so I tried to tweak every setting I could find related to multiple check-in and locking and the sort.

I'm now at a point where I can open, edit and save, aspx.cs files without Visual Studio automatically locking the file, but when I edit a .cs file, it still gets locked up. Why? Aren't they both .cs files? How can I prevent those damned locks?